# ALTER TABLE case insensitivity

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have tried to add constraint to a table to accept any file name that ended with `(JPG)` regardless of case sensitivity. So the table should accept any entry that contain any files that ended with `(JPG)`,`(Jpg)`,`(jPg)`, etc.

Here is my statement below but only accept upper case. Any help please?

This is in Oracle SQL Developer.

```
ALTER TABLE P_SPECIES ADD CONSTRAINT IMAGEFILE CHECK (SPECIES_IMAGEFILE like ('%.jpg'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is always lower case `SPECIES_IMAGEFILE` for the constraint.

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE P_SPECIES ADD CONSTRAINT IMAGEFILE CHECK (LOWER(SPECIES_IMAGEFILE) like ('%.jpg'))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I spent over three hours looking for solution but no luck.